# Is Customising Individual Accounts Advisable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

In what scenarios is the individual accounts concept useful/helpful - consider no use of claim based?
I intend to customize the individual accounts...could not find much documentation on the same. Few articles suggested against customizing it.

So should we try to customize the individual accounts concept or does it make the code too complex? If not then please provide some example for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had done some customization of ASP.NET Identity recently in a few projects. It isn't too hard actually, depending on what you want to do. Customizing the user object should be the most ask place for. This is easy if you know how the **IdentityUser** object looks like. If you want to change the underlying database: there are some projects on GitHub. With them you can use RavenDB, MongoDB, MySQL, etc.

Compared to other membership systems on the .NET stack Identity is easy to customize, because it isn't a big framework. The biggest drawback is the missing documentation, but some guys in the community have written some nice articles (like [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/) or [Dominick Baier](http://leastprivilege.com/)).